# Setting a conditional callback based on a two model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback, associations

I have a `Task` that belongs to a `User` (aliased as `owner`). A task has a time zone and a user has a time zone. I don't require that the user selects their time zone at registration. Therefore when they create a task and select a time zone in that particular form (which is required) I'd like to take that value and save it also as the user's time zone.

I have a working `before_save` callback setup but don't won't to call it on every save if the `owner` already has a time zone on record. I tried setting a conditional but get the error:

`undefined local variable or method 'owner' for #<Class:0x007fcf7fae9510>`

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: time_zone

   has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

**Task**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: :owner_id, :time_zone

  before_save :assign_owner_time_zone if !owner.time_zone

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"

  private
    def assign_owner_time_zone
      owner.update_attribute(:time_zone, time_zone)
    end
end
```

Comment: At which line you get that error?

Comment: `before_save :assign_owner_time_zone if !owner.time_zone`

Comment: Try this `before_save :assign_owner_time_zone, if: Proc.new { |task| !task.owner.time_zone.present? }`

Comment: Awesome! That seemed to do the trick. In your answer could you also explain what's going on there? I haven't used a callback in that manner before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**conditional callbacks**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks) like this

```
before_save :assign_owner_time_zone, if: Proc.new { |task| !task.owner.time_zone.present? }
```

Comment: Would you recommend delegating the owner's time zone to avoid violating Demeter's Law? So for example inside the Proc's block: `!task.owner_time_zone.present?`

Comment: @CarlEdwards I can't say because it doesn't make any difference i guess :)